# При включенных Advanced Custom Fields не работают встроенные

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Скачал и установил на готовом проекте Advanced Custom Fields ( до этого уже был реализован функционал встроеных кастом филдов). 
Теперь встроенные не работают, а работают только от плагина. Когда деактивирую плагин - встроенные появляются в админке в постах.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, речь о произвольных полях WordPress.

Плагин ACF может скрывать произвольные поля. Откройте настройки группы полей ACF, прокрутите вниз до настроек, увидите примерно такие настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Снимите галочку с "Группа полей".

На странице записи в консоли в верхнем правом углу откройте "Настройки экрана" и поставьте галочку в "Произвольные поля"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увидите блок произвольных полей в записи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в группе полей галочка не была проставлена(я попробовал поставить галочку а потом убрать её, но в настройках экрана их так и не появилось ), они появляются только лишь когда я деактивирую плагин .

Comment: Проверил на другом сайте - действительно, при установке ACF произвольные поля не скрываются. У вас именно Произвольные поля WordPress пропадают?

Comment: да, встроенные в Wordpress только скрываются...

Comment: И в настройках экрана вверху пропадает поле "Произвольные поля"?

Comment: Да, вот скрин настроек когда я деактивировал плагин https://snag.gy/Lksg8C.jpg

Comment: А вот при включенном плагине - https://snag.gy/y4JVHh.jpg

Comment: Это странно. Попытайтесь найти, с чем он конфликтует. Отключите все остальные плагины, смените тему на стандартную.

Comment: Может ли это быть из-за того что я в вордпрессе не настроил подключение через фтп ? Я просто папку с плагинами закидываю на фтп через файлзиллу, и потом с админки этот плагин активирую .

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68862/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-nick).

Answer (score 2):

Нужно в файл functions темы добавить:

```
add_filter('acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false');
```